# A relative clause in a relative clause (Nested relative clauses)

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

What I want to say is something as follows,

> Up to now, there is no person who can find the mistake of person who does not care about the possibility of the existence of living things on places other than the earth.

My attempt is as follows. Could you verify whether or not my translation correct? Any comment and correction are highly appreciated.

> 地球以外の所に生物が存在する可能性を気にしない人の間違いことを見つける人は今までもまだいない。

Comment: までも まだ is reduplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

> 地球以外の場所に生命体が存在する可能性など気にも[留]{と}めない人の[過]{あやま}ちを[指摘]{してき}できた(or できる)人は、(or 見つけられた人は、)今までのところ誰もいない。

or a bit less literally...

> 地球以外の場所に生命体が存在する(or 地球外生命体の存在の)可能性など気にも留めない人のどこがいけないかを指摘できた(orできる)人は、今のところ誰もいない。

Comment: 「地球外生命体の存在の可能性を無視する人たちがどういう点で間違ってるかを指摘できた人は、今まで誰もいない。」って意味かな？と思ったんですが。。。

Answer (score 1):

First sentence is some imcomprehensive.
地球以外の所に生物が存在する可能性に気づかない～.
Your sentence is simply
→宇宙に生物がいないと言ってる人の間違いを発見できない。Is this right?

By the way,because some virus live in various environment,it is not strange that there are living things in some planets of universe.

Comment: 「宇宙人がいないと言ってる人」は「地球以外の所に生物が存在する可能性を気にしない人」と意味が違うと思います。

Answer (score 1):

The original English sentence seems awkward (if not grammatically incorrect) and I feel it may not be what you really mean to say. I'm going to guess you meant this:

> Up to now, one could not find fault with someone who does not care about the possibility of the existence of living things on places other than the earth.

While this could possibly be translated with an expression like "非難する" or "ケチをつける" (for the 'find fault' part), let me give you my attempt at a natural, non-literal translation.

> 今まで、地球以外の所に生物が存在する可能性を全く気にしない人が居てもおかしくないと言えるでしょう。

Knowing more of the context (like if the next sentence is talking about the discovery of aliens) might help refine the translation to make it fit better into the whole.